# Excel 2013: Analyzing Multiple Dates within a single Cell using IF statements

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Is there are way to analyze multiple dates within an a single cell in Excel using IF statements?

For Example, I have the following dates in a single cell (A1):
`1/2/23, 4/6/23, 10/3/23`

Is there are to say if any of the values in (A1)>= 4/1/223 AND <= 9/30/23 then return a "Yes"?

Comment: If you can, split the cells with the “LEFT” command, and the analyze the newly created cells that way. No way I know to do this with native Excel

Comment: Use the text to column feature to split the dates along the `,` and then run the formulas you want.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `Excel 2013` then with the <kbd>FILTERXML()</kbd> function (**Windows Excel 2013+**), you can use:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=IF(SUM((FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b")>DATE(2023,4,1))*
  (FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b")<=DATE(2023,9,30))),"Yes","No")
```

---

If you need more information on <kbd>FILTERXML()</kbd> then you might like to read this post **[Excel - Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml)** from **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv) Sir**.

---

Also note depending on one's excel version, may need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

---

If you have only three dates, delimited by a comma, you could try the following as well.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=((--LEFT(A1,FIND(", ",A1)-1)>45017)*
  (--LEFT(A1,FIND(", ",A1)-1)<=45199))+
  ((--SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(", ",A1)+1,8)),",",)>45017)*
  (--SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(", ",A1)+1,8)),",",)<=45199))+
  ((--TRIM(RIGHT(A1,8))>45017)*
  (--TRIM(RIGHT(A1,8))<=45199))
```

---

Where `+` operator used as <kbd>OR()</kbd> function, while `*` used as <kbd>AND()</kbd>

---

In Modern Excel Versions aka `MS365` it literally becomes more easy, sleek and simpler, adding only as an alternative for future reference:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, --TEXTSPLIT(A1,", "),
     IF(SUM((α>45017)*(α<=45199)),"Yes","No"))
```

---

Comment: FILTERXML is indeed a nice option here. @JvdV could we get FILTERXML to check if the values are within the date range in one go maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(
    SUM(
        (--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)*(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A$1,",",""))))-1)+1,LEN(A1)))>45017)
        *
        (--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)*(ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))))-1)+1,LEN(A1)))<=45199)),
    "Yes",
    "No")
```

This requires being entered with `Ctrl+ shift enter`

You may want to use helpers instead. Let me know if this is operating too slow.